# Value to indicate to use default

Tags: scala, implicit

In Scala I would like to have something like this

**TokenizerExample.scala**

```
class TokenizerExample private (whateva : Any)(implicit val separator : Char = '.') {

    def this(data2Tokenize : String)(implicit s : Char) {
        this("", s) //call to base constructor
    }

    def this(data2Tokenize : Array[Char])(implicit s : Char) { {
        this("", s) //call to base constructor
    }

}
```

what I would like to achieve is to allow the user to call any of the two public constructors either providing or not the separator, but if they do NOT provide the separator automatically take the one in the base constructor, I was wondering if there is a value that I can pass to the base constructor so that scala use the default on the private base constructor.

what I would like to avoid it to do the next in each constructor

```
    def this(_3rdConstructor : SytringBuilder)(implicit s : Char = '.')  ...
```

I tried this in many different ways, with the values being implicit, with the separator as a `Option`, but I do not get a result that I actually like, specially because scala complains about having implicit values in multiple constructors (which kind of defeats the purpose of having them). Is there a way to achieve that behavior in a nice way without

- 1) forcing the user to provide a separator.
- 2) go into "bad-practices" by passing null values and then validating them (specially because that would not allow my separator to be a `val` in the constructor.
- 3) creating YET ANOTHER LANGUAGE just because I dislike a small little thing about one of them :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly advice you against using implicits for this purpose. The resolution rules are rather complex, and it makes the code extremely hard to follow, because it is almost impossible to tell what value the constructor will end up receiving without the debugger.

If all you are trying to do is avoid defining the default in multiple places, just define it in a companion object:

```
object Foo {
    val defaultParam = ','
}
class Foo {
   import Foo.defaultParam
   def this(data: String, param: Char = defaultParam) = ???
   def this(data: List[Char], param: Char = defaultParam) = ???
   // etc ...
}
```

If you insist on using implicits, you can use a similar approach to the above: just make `defaultParam` definition `implicit`, drop the defaults, replacing them with implicit lists, and then `import Foo._` in scope where you are making the call. But, really, don't do that: it adds no value, and only has disadvantages in this case.

Comment: Yup, just as I supposed, anyhow I will leave the question as unanswered to see if someone comes up with a better idea any good suggestion or workaround, and if none does, then I will accept your answer. Thanks @Dima

Comment: Maybe, I could come up with a "workaround" too, if I understood better what  exactly it is you are "working around" :)
Can you explain what about this solution you find needing improvement?

(I don't really care much about the answer being accepted, just trying to help)

Comment: well it is pretty much that I want a "chain of responsibility" for some arguments in my constructor, in a way that I can end up with a "val" (in java terms `public final` variable, containing the "separator"), I know I can do it by having a different name in the parameter of the constructor and then assigning it to a `val separator` by myself, but that is not a very smart use of memory and variables, and also i consider better having the proper names in my arguments (in this case separator) so that the user can call them as `new TockenizerExample(separator='/' , data="bla")

Comment: I don't see what is different here from my example? Is it that I just omitted the the private constructor? `class Foo private (val data: Any, val param: Char = Foo.defaultParam)` Is   this what you are after, or am I still missing something? And yes, this way, you can still do `new Foo(data="bar", param=',')`, so ... still don't see what's the problem